# If limit of $f(n)$ is zero then the operator is compact

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I want to prove the following:

*Suppose $\mathfrak{H}$ is the Hilbertspace $l^2(\Bbb{N})$ and $T_f$ the multiplication operator on $\mathfrak{H}$, thus $T_f\psi=f\psi$ for $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$. Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{|f(n)|}=0$. Then $T_f$ is compact.*

Can one prove this with finite rank operators or just with Bolzano-Weierstrass?
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can go both ways. Using finite rank operators seems easier to me, though. Bolzano-Weierstrass is also possible but requires a careful application of the diagonal procedure.